Symmetry of a Gaussian product
Background
Let $y, V_1, V_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be three given vectors and let $R\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be a covariance matrix.
Then, consider the following function
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}(y;V_1,V_2)&\triangleq \frac{\mathcal{N}(B; 0, R)}{\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{B'R^{-1}A}{\sqrt{A'R^{-1}A}}; 0, 1\right)}
\frac{\Phi\left(\frac{A'R^{-1}A+B'R^{-1}A}{\sqrt{A'R^{-1}A}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B'R^{-1}A}{\sqrt{A'R^{-1}A}}\right)
}{\sqrt{A'R^{-1}A}}\\
B&\triangleq V_1 - y \\
A&\triangleq V_2 - V_1
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \Sigma) \triangleq ((2\pi)^n\,\mathrm{det}R)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\, \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)' \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)
\end{equation}
is the $n$-variate Gaussian PDF (with $n\triangleq \mathrm{dim}\,x$) and
\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)\triangleq \int_{-\infty}^x \exp\left(-\frac{\beta^2}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\beta
\end{equation}
is the CDF of the univariate Gaussian PDF $\mathcal{N}(x; 0, 1)$. If my derivation is correct, equation $(1)$ should be the PDF of $y=z+v$, where $v\sim\mathcal{N}(v; 0, R)$ and $z$ uniformly distributed over the segment connecting $V_1$ and $V_2$.
Problem
As a sanity check, the following relation should hold
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(y; V_2, V_1)=\mathcal{L}(y; V_1, V_2)
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
that is, the value of $\mathcal{L}$ should not change by swapping the order of the two vertices (because this operation does not change the underlying segment).
Clearly, $A'R^{-1}A$ (and its square root) doesn't change by swapping $V_1$ and $V_2$, but the cross product $B'R^{-1}A$ does (so that, it is not clear if $(2)$ is true or not).
My attempt to prove (2)
To simplify the problem, in a first instance we can consider $R=\sigma^2 I$ with $I$ being the $2\times2$ identity matrix. After some simple manipulations it turns out the simplified expression
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(y;V_1,V_2)=\mathcal{N}(B'B; B'A, \sigma^2)\frac{\Phi\left(\frac{A'A+B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)}{\sqrt{A'A}}
\end{equation}
Since $\sqrt{A'A}$ is already symmetric, the objective is to show that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(B_2'B_2; B_2'A_2, \sigma^2)\left[
\Phi\left(\frac{A_2'A_2+B_2'A_2}{\sigma\sqrt{A_2'A_2}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B_2'A_2}{\sigma\sqrt{A_2'A_2}}\right)\right]=
\mathcal{N}(B_1'B_1; B_1'A_1, \sigma^2)\left[
\Phi\left(\frac{A_1'A_1+B_1'A_1}{\sigma\sqrt{A_1'A_1}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B_1'A_1}{\sigma\sqrt{A_1'A_1}}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
B_1 &\triangleq V_1 - y\\
A_1 &\triangleq V_2 - V_1
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
B_2 &\triangleq V_2 - y\\
A_2 &\triangleq V_1 - V_2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, at this point I get stuck.
Question
Is $(2)$ true?
EDIT
I've made a mistake in the simplification of $\mathcal{L}$. The correct formula is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(y;V_1,V_2)=\mathcal{N}\left(\sqrt{B'B- \left(\frac{B'A}{A'A}\right)^2}; 0 ,\sigma^2\right)\frac{\Phi\left(\frac{A'A+B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)}{\sqrt{A'A}}
\end{equation}
which can be further simplified as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(y;V_1,V_2)=\mathcal{N}\left(\sqrt{(B'B)(A'A)- \left(B'A\right)^2}; 0 ,\sigma^2 A'A\right)\left[\Phi\left(\frac{A'A+B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)-
\Phi\left(\frac{B'A}{\sigma\sqrt{A'A}}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
